# error TS2345: Argument of type '(a: Test, b: Test) => boolean | 1' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Test, b: Test) => number'

Tags: javascript, typescript

sorry for long subject, I just don't understand the response.

my code:

```
this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a[5]===null) {
       // console.log(a[5]);
        return 1;

      }
        if (firmaSortOrder) {
          return a[5] > b[5];
        }
        else {
          return b[5] > a[5];
        }

    });
```

js throws:
error TS2345: 
Argument of type '(a: Rezerwacja, b: Rezerwacja) => boolean | 1' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Rezerwacja, b: Rezerwacja) => number'.
  Type 'boolean | 1' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: return a[5] - b[5], and b[5] - a[5]

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN description of sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), sort compare function has to return a number. Your first condition returns number, but other two returns boolean values. Below code should work.

```
this.rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a[5] === null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (firmaSortOrder) {
        return a[5] - b[5];
    }
    return b[5] - a[5];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typescript compilation error. the signature in rezerwacjeFilteredByseaarchInput is incorrect. It should  only return number values (this is what the message is saying ) but in its body you can read that it can return the boolean values.

Comment: "It should only return boolean values" the message is the opposite. Comparator should always return a number simply because you can't represent 3 possible comparison outcomes with a boolean flag.

Comment: you are totally right. I misread the error message and edited my answer. the comparator function must only return number (for the reason you cited) but by returning the result of a comparison it returns boolean which is incorrect and raises a typescript compilation error